# How to join array values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have **array 1**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recomendation_id] => 3588
            [employee_id] => 90141063
            [attendance_type_id] => 2
            [start_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:00
            [end_dtm] => 
            [request_message] => test notif
            [recomendation_status_id] => 1
            [last_update_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:43
            [employee_name] => Nike Yulistia Angreni
            [attd_type_name] => Permittance
            [status_name] => Request
        )

)
```

And **array 2**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valuator1] => Wulan  Lastia Permana
        )
)
```

I want to make array values in one array. I want result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recomendation_id] => 3588
            [employee_id] => 90141063
            [attendance_type_id] => 2
            [start_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:00
            [end_dtm] => 
            [request_message] => test notif
            [recomendation_status_id] => 1
            [last_update_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:43
            [employee_name] => Nike Yulistia Angreni
            [attd_type_name] => Permittance
            [status_name] => Request
            [valuator1] => Wulan  Lastia Permana
        )
)
```

Is it possible to join like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php):

```
<?php

$arr1 = Array
(
     Array
        (
            "recomendation_id" => 3588,
            "employee_id" => 90141063,
            "attendance_type_id" => 2,
            "start_dtm" => "2016-05-17 10:32:00",
            "end_dtm" => "",
            "request_message" => "test notif",
            "recomendation_status_id" => 1,
            "last_update_dtm" => "2016-05-17 10:32:43",
            "employee_name" => "Nike Yulistia Angreni",
            "attd_type_name" => "Permittance",
            "status_name" => "Request"
        )

);
$arr2 = Array
(
    Array
        (
            "valuator1" => "Wulan  Lastia Permana"
        )
);

print_r(array_replace_recursive($arr1,$arr2));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recomendation_id] => 3588
            [employee_id] => 90141063
            [attendance_type_id] => 2
            [start_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:00
            [end_dtm] => 
            [request_message] => test notif
            [recomendation_status_id] => 1
            [last_update_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:43
            [employee_name] => Nike Yulistia Angreni
            [attd_type_name] => Permittance
            [status_name] => Request
            [valuator1] => Wulan  Lastia Permana
        )

)
```

Your [Eval](https://eval.in/572367)

---

If you use [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), your [output](https://eval.in/572368) will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recomendation_id] => 3588
            [employee_id] => 90141063
            [attendance_type_id] => 2
            [start_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:00
            [end_dtm] => 
            [request_message] => test notif
            [recomendation_status_id] => 1
            [last_update_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:43
            [employee_name] => Nike Yulistia Angreni
            [attd_type_name] => Permittance
            [status_name] => Request
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valuator1] => Wulan  Lastia Permana
        )

)
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know these functions. Won't `array_replace_recursive` overwrite old values? Or can it add new values as well?

Comment: @Peter `array_replace_recursive` will replace the old values

Comment: @NikeYulistiaAngreni Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) function

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: The output of above is different than what is expected.

Comment: `array_merge_recursive` will add the value to a different subarray.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Let your first array is `$arr1` and second array is `$arr2`.

Just assign a new field to your first array, Your first array will be updated with the second array's `key, value pair`.

```
$arr1[0]['valuator1'] = $arr2[0]['valuator1'];

print_r($arr1);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recomendation_id] => 3588
            [employee_id] => 90141063
            [attendance_type_id] => 2
            [start_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:00
            [end_dtm] => 
            [request_message] => test notif
            [recomendation_status_id] => 1
            [last_update_dtm] => 2016-05-17 10:32:43
            [employee_name] => Nike Yulistia Angreni
            [attd_type_name] => Permittance
            [status_name] => Request
            [valuator1] => Wulan  Lastia Permana
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best option in my opinion but it will still tackle your issue.

```
foreach ($arr2 as $k => $v) {
    $arr1[$key] = array_merge($arr1[$key], $v);
}
```

This will loop through the second array and merge each value with the first array.

Note: Your array keys should be the same in both arrays for this to work.