# Merge Two Array in PHP got from a select query : UPDATE

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two Array Like this, The array_replace_recursive() not working in this case, Since i edited the same for more clarification.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 1
            [totalComments] => 5
            [commentsPoints] => 900
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 460
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 2
            [totalComments] => 4
            [commentsPoints] => 720
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 24
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 3
            [totalComments] => 4
            [commentsPoints] => 720
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 24
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 18
            [totalComments] => 4
            [commentsPoints] => 720
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 24
        )

)
```

AND

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 1
            [totalLikesGiven] => 5
            [likesGivenOnTopicPoints] => 36
            [likesGivenOnReplyPoints] => 108
            [likesGivenOnBlogPoints] => 36
            [DateDiffTopicpoints] => 1
            [DateDiffReplypoints] => 3
            [DateDiffBlogpoints] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 3
            [totalLikesGiven] => 1
            [likesGivenOnTopicPoints] => 0
            [likesGivenOnReplyPoints] => 0
            [likesGivenOnBlogPoints] => 36
            [DateDiffTopicpoints] => 0
            [DateDiffReplypoints] => 0
            [DateDiffBlogpoints] => 1
        )

)
```

I like a result LIKE this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 1
            [totalComments] => 5
            [commentsPoints] => 900
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 460
            [totalLikesGiven] => 5
            [likesGivenOnTopicPoints] => 36
            [likesGivenOnReplyPoints] => 108
            [likesGivenOnBlogPoints] => 36
            [DateDiffTopicpoints] => 1
            [DateDiffReplypoints] => 3
            [DateDiffBlogpoints] => 1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 2
            [totalComments] => 4
            [commentsPoints] => 720
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 24
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 3
            [totalComments] => 4
            [commentsPoints] => 720
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 24
            [totalLikesGiven] => 1
            [likesGivenOnTopicPoints] => 0
            [likesGivenOnReplyPoints] => 0
            [likesGivenOnBlogPoints] => 36
            [DateDiffTopicpoints] => 0
            [DateDiffReplypoints] => 0
            [DateDiffBlogpoints] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Author] => 18
            [totalComments] => 4
            [commentsPoints] => 720
            [commentDateDiffpoints] => 24
        )

)
```

Please help how can I do the same in PHP.

Comment: A tip for objects in arrays. It helps immensely mostly the primary key in your database to use as a key for the array. 
So that you can more quickly find your objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php):

```
$finalArr = array_replace_recursive($arr1,$arr2);
```

There is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269492/5447994). And more such questions in SO.

Comment: Thanks It works with just an update, and that is convert both the stdClass Objects to an array by using $arr1 = json_decode(json_encode($arr1), true); $arr2 = json_decode(json_encode($arr2), true); AND finally use $finalArr = array_replace_recursive($arr1,$arr2);

Comment: The array_replace_recursive() function not working when the first and second both array has unique values, it is not adding both records.

Comment: Then go for `array_merge_recursive` in that case

Comment: OK, now i got multiple records against the same [Author] how to group them in a single record within the same array, Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Use array merge php function.
[PHP array merge function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @Dagon, ok. two more minuses and you achieve your goal