# Combining multiple JSON arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to combine the following arrays based on a matching field "employerPayeReference" of the below arrays

**Array 1:**

```
{
    "employments": [
    {
       "employerPayeReference": "123/AB456",
       "payFromEmployment": 100.00
    },
    {
       "employerPayeReference": "456/AB456",
       "payFromEmployment": 100.00
    }
]
}
```

**Array 2:**

```
{
  "employments": [
    {
      "employerPayeReference": "123/AB456",
      "taxTakenOffPay": 10.00
    },
    {
      "employerPayeReference": "456/AB456",
      "taxTakenOffPay": 15.00
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I arrive at an array that looks like this

```
{
  "employments": [
    {
      "employerPayeReference": "123/AB456",
      "payFromEmployment": 100.00
      "taxTakenOffPay": 10.00
    },
    {
      "employerPayeReference": "456/AB456",
      "payFromEmployment": 100.00
      "taxTakenOffPay": 15.00
    }
  ]
}
```

(i.e) it is combined based on the employerPayeReference matching. Any help appreciated

Comment: What did you try, and why did it not work?

Comment: I am repeating this loop on each array, but it relies on the payeref being in the same order in each array which is not always the case.

foreach($input as $parent) {
    foreach($parent as $values) {
        echo "<BR>";
        echo $values[employerPayeReference];
        echo $values[employerName];
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive) to achieve the result. But since, it work with arrays, you need to convert your json to array using `json_decode` and then encode using `json_encode` to achieve desired result.

```
$arr1 = '{
    "employments": [
    {
       "employerPayeReference": "123/AB456",
       "payFromEmployment": 100.00
    },
    {
       "employerPayeReference": "456/AB456",
       "payFromEmployment": 100.00
    }
]
}';

$arr2 = '{
  "employments": [
    {
      "employerPayeReference": "123/AB456",
      "taxTakenOffPay": 10.00
    },
    {
      "employerPayeReference": "456/AB456",
      "taxTakenOffPay": 15.00
    }
  ]
}';

$arr1 = json_decode($arr1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($arr2, true);

$finalArr = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);

echo json_encode($finalArr);
```

---

**One liner:**

```
echo json_encode(array_replace_recursive(json_decode($arr1, true), json_decode($arr2, true)));
```

---

There is a similar approach dealing with arrays from another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269492/5447994)

Comment: Thank you do much! Exactly what i was looking for!