# Merge two arrays, replacing values of same key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays

First Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [352] => 1
            [128] => 
            [64] => 
            [70] => 2
        )
)
```

Second array is like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [128] => 1.5
        )
)
```

I want to make final array like this.(i want to store the matching into the main array in this example it is **128 -> 1.5**) how can i do it.?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [352] => 1
            [128] => 1.5
            [64] =>  
            [70] => 2
        )

)
```

here is my array variables:

```
print_r($listskilssresult);
print_r($listskilssresultmatching);
```

Comment: `array_merge()` would help.

Comment: Maybe there's not quite enough information. Do you only want to store the matches if the value for the first array is blank?. Are there other conditions? What if the same key exists in both arrays but they have different values? You'll have to account for all the conditions before you can code this out properly.

Comment: I agree with Difster, this question does not contain a sufficiently clear [mcve]. Depending on how the real project data looks, `array_replace_recursive()` may actually do harm to the data.  Do we need to respect all keys in all levels whe replacing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use [`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive)

```
$listskilssresult = [
    [
        352 => 1,
        128 => '',
        64  => '',
        70  => 2
    ]
];

$listskilssresultmatching = [
    [
        128 => 1.5
    ]
];


print_r(array_replace_recursive($listskilssresult, $listskilssresultmatching));
```

**Prints :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [352] => 1
            [128] => 1.5
            [64] => 
            [70] => 2
        )

)
```

---

Know the difference between `array_replace_recursive` and `array_merge_recursive` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269492/5447994)

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to your question. If you want to make something more automated, you can create a function. But this will do what you want:

```
<?php

  $array1 = [[352 => 1, 128 => null, 64 => null, 70 => 2]];
  $array2 = [[128 => 1.5]];

  $keys1 = array_keys($array1[0]);
  $keys2 = array_keys($array2[0]);

  foreach ($keys1 as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $keys2)) {
      $array1[0][$value] = $array2[0][$value];
      unset($array2[0][$value]);
    }
  }

  if (!empty($array2[0])) {
    foreach ($array2[0] as $key => $value) {
      $array1[0][$key] = $value;
      unset($array2[0][$key]);
    }
  }

  print_r($array1[0]);
?>
```

The last if statement will add key + value from the 2nd array to the first if no match was found for them (from the foreach statement). You can just delete that condition if you just want to add only matching keys.

Answer (score 0):

[array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) is the best solution!

```
$old_array = Array('my_index1' => Array('1' => 'A', '2' => 'B'), 'my_index2' => Array('1' => 'C', '2' => 'D'));
$new_array = Array('my_index2' => Array('2' => 'Z'));
$result = array_replace_recursive($old_array, $new_array);

//Result : Array('my_index1' => Array('1' => 'A', '2' => 'B'), 'my_index2' => Array('1' => 'C', '2' => 'Z'));
```

Answer (score -1):

For this solution, you have to use `array_merge()` built-in php function.

**Syntax:**

```
$finalArray =   array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($finalArray)
```

**Example:**

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score -2):

array_merge would do the job for you:

```
array_merge($listskilssresult,$listskilssresultmatching)
```

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [352] => 1
            [128] => 
            [64] => 
            [23] => 
            [70] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [128] => 1.5
        )

)`
when i use array merge it is coming like this